# Neo4j - Grab the relationships and their properties of a large-degree node is slow

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a graph with 2,324,835 nodes and 170,075,768 edges.
After using Neo4j's java `BatchInserter` to insert the graph into Neo4j, I'm trying to grab the relationships on a node with degree 29,000 and get an int property on each of these relationships.
The grabbing process is done by embedded java application of Neo4j.
It takes 266s to get all the information I need at the first time, then I shutdown the database, close the java application and start it again.
In the second time, I repeat the same process on the same node, but it only takes 11s to finish my task this time.
Is this behavior reasonable? Why would it take so long for the first time? I think it's not the caching problem since I reopen the java application and the cache in memory should have gone?

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.6 on a Linux machine with openjdk-7.
The java library is called by my scala application.

Comment: When you say: *grab the relationships on a node with degree 29,000*. What do you mean by that? Is degree some property on the node?

Comment: @wassgren, degree is a common term (accepted within neo4j as well) that refers to a number of relationships connected to node.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And could you possibly provide the query as well (assuming you are using cypher)?

Comment: @wassgren I'm not using Cypher, I use the Neo4j Java API by `Node.getRelationships()`

Comment: It is the time needed to fetch all the relationships from the different store files (when they are not mapped into memory by the OS yet), if you use a faster disk (SSD) or initial warmup of the store files `for file in graph.db/*; do dd if=$file of=/dev/null bs=1M;done`, it also might hep to reorg your relationships or rework your model, Perhaps you have some discrimination on the relationship via properties that should move to a rel-type.

Comment: You can also configure the db-memory-mapping and heap sizes and potentially warm up the caches by fetching nodes and their rels upfront. Not sure what your use-case is.